# Overcome limit when silect into @ text variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select a group_concat into variable @s

In the procedure I'm using this but get an error

`Error Code: 1406 Data too long for column 'result' at row 9552`

```sql
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;

SET @query=CONCAT( 
'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\'<url><loc>https://www.example.com/product/\',seo_url,\'.html</loc></url>\' SEPARATOR \'\r\n\')FROM ',
@cpy,'products WHERE web_vis_each OR web_vis_pair ORDER BY group_id,position,make,model;'
);
--
PREPARE sql_query FROM @query;
EXECUTE sql_query;
```

Comment: Well it means what is says, the data is too long after 9551 rows

Comment: the table actually has 9551 rows so I thought it was strange. I've also tried it in a function DECLARE j LONGTEXT DEFAULT '';

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('<url><loc>https://www.example.com/product/',seo_url,'.html</loc></url>' SEPARATOR '\r\n')
FROM 1_products WHERE web_vis_each OR web_vis_pair ORDER BY group_id,position,make,model INTO j;

Comment: Try proccessing the first 100 rows and see if  you like the result just as a diagnostic tool.  You really want GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the fields for the entire table in one string, not using GROUP BY?